# Update capitalization of contact names

Tags: wordpress, contacts

I was hoping to find an extension that would correct the capitalization of first last names - for example, if someone entered a name in all lowercase or all uppercase, it would change the first letter of the name to uppercase.

It looks like the Capitalisation Corrector does just this. https://civicrm.org/extensions/capitalisation-corrector. But I can't find it as a scheduled job, or in the extension directory. I tried using the Normalise the Data extension but that does not work for my purposes.

I am currently using CiviCRM 5.18.2 with WordPress. Does the Capitalisation Corrector work with WordPress? Is there another way I can install it?

Answer (score 1):

None of the extension you mentioned have schedule job or script to fix historical data, we had to write a script to update historical data when the extension was installed, and going forward extension managed to capitalize the name.

Answer (score 1):

The [Capitalisation Corrector](https://civicrm.org/extensions/capitalisation-corrector) is not available for download via the `Administer > System Settings > Extensions` interface so you need to get the extension files on to the system some other way.

There are multiple ways to do this depending on the access you have, but you need to get the files from the [latest release](https://github.com/futurefirst/capscorrect/archive/1.1.zip) (see Download link on the extension page) extracted into your extensions directory.  If you don't know where your extensions directory is, check `Administer > System Settings > Directories`

Once you have done that, go to the Extensions page again, click Refresh and you should see the extension available for installation.  Click Install.

When it has finished installing you will then find the scheduled job labelled "Call Contacts.CorrectNameCasesJob API (Daily)"

I have not tested on WP but I would expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to script using mysql to correct first_name field to "First" and last_name field to "Lastname", but it's difficult though not to mess up last names like "McArthur" or hyphenated first names like "Mary-Beth".

Answer (score 0):

This [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividesk-normalize) might be what you're looking for. I use it, works great!